# Regular Expression for timestamp field

Tags: regex

I have a regex for the timestamp of format `YYYY:MM:DD HH:MM:SS`

```
 var r6 = /[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]) (2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]/;
```

Which I have made.
I want to modify this to make regex to validate this timestamp field.

```
2017-01-01 00:00:00.0
```

At the end user can input any no of spaces. But after the date only 1 space is allowed before begining of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should work:

```
(?=[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]\s*).*
```

As you can check [here](https://regex101.com/r/jRPqnF/5)

Comment: ,140,145,147, or 140,145,147 what will be the regex for this can u please tell also. It should only accept numerals and only one single comma before the starting of integer or in between the integer.